# Black body of questions/answers

Tags: bug, android-app

With the current android app the bodies of questions/answers show all black, with links (URLs) in blue and equations in grey.

Just updated, no idea what version it is now.

Comment: Even this shows black. BTW, version is 1.0.41

Comment: Comments show correctly.

Comment: Weird. On MSE after restarting they show OK, her it is still black

Comment: After posting the above, everything is black again

Comment: Black background is not only question/answer but also profile textfield. The black bg seems to happen in all selectable `TextField`s.